# how to display posts of a particular category in front page via tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, post, tabs, categories

i inserted some of bootstrap navigation-tabs at the head of front page, that any of this tabs is used for a Specified category of posts.
how can i click on one of this tabs and posts of a certain category that i want, shown on that tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to add your loop-filter and query through the categories specificly on every tab. so like

```
<?php global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&cat=12'); // only show posts from category with the ID 12 ?>

<?php // YOUR USUAL LOOP HERE ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

You could also exclude categories

```
<?php global $query_string; // required
$posts = query_posts($query_string.'&cat=-12'); // Show al posts that are NOT in category with ID 12 ?>

<?php // YOUR USUAL LOOP HERE ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

Here is the wordpress docu http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/query_posts take a look at "Combining Parameters"

has allready been answered here: [Only show specific category in wordpress loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15017370/only-show-specific-category-in-wordpress-loop)